# Understanding viewport

Tags: html, google-chrome, viewport

I'm trying to understand the viewport concept. I use the following test HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta  name="viewport" content="width=1500, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test page to understand view port</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div>2. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I set viewport width to be 1500, I tell the browser that the page was designed for 1500px wide screen. So I expect my Chrome to scale the page to my HTC One's small screen and I expected font to be quite small. But that's what I get:

[image]

Could someone explain me this result?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's appearing like that is because you're telling the viewport to render the content as if the screen's width is 1500 pixels wide. Clearly this device doesn't have a width of 1500 so the content appears very large.

This is a really good page that will summarise everything to do with the viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Try setting the width like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`.